# Applying class to all children of an element

Tags: html, css, web

I'm wondering if it's possible (without using JS) to state that all children of `tr.myRow` have a certain class. I'm trying to use W3.CSS and I want every `<td>` element to be `w3-border` class. Now the code has to look like this:

```
<table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="w3-border">A</td>
        <td class="w3-border">B</td>
        <td class="w3-border">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

which is not elegant.

I would appreciate any hints

Comment: Have a certain class or a certain set of properties? Latter is possible, former is not.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on the basics of CSS.

Comment: The typical way would be to define not a `.w3-border` but `.w3-table tr td` in CSS and handle things that way.

Comment: Thing is that I didn't define w3-table nor w3-border; it's from a framework

Comment: Simply, **No**...it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question exactly as you worded it - you are not able to assign classes to HTML elements via bare CSS. For this, specifically, you would need to use javascript, or a CSS extension like SCSS.

I am, however, assuming you are trying to assign *properties/values* to the actual `td` - which you wouldn't need class assignment for.

`tr.myRow * { /* Add your styles here */ }`

This method does not answer your question, but does provide a way to produce the same result you are most likely looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
.w3-table tr td {//add your css}
```

Comment: This allows you to provide CSS properties, not adding a class as requested.  This may solve the OPs question.